# How to refresh current page with play framework?

Tags: playframework

Right now, in Play if I want to reload current page I have to do something like that:

```
public static Result action(){
    if(status==0){
      //some actions
      return redirect(routes.pathToController())
    }else{
      return redirect(routes.pathToControllerThatDisplaysCurrentPage())
}
```

If I want to simulate the effect of user pressing refresh page, is it possible to do something like:

```
public static Result action(){
   if(status==0){
      //some actions
      return redirect(routes.pathToController())
    }else{
      return redirect(refreshCurrentPage())
}
```

The reason I want to do that is so that I don't have to save current parameters, and simply make the page reload with the same as before.

Comment: By reloading a page I understand an action in client's browser. How do you want to refresh a page on client's side from a server? Aren't you looking for a javascript code?

Comment: It's job for JS not backend...

Comment: I want to create a button, which after pressing, would refresh the webpage

Comment: `<input type="button" value="Reload Page" onClick="window.location.reload()">`

Comment: The thing is I do not know If I want to reload the page or do something else before doing some operations on server side. The button would sometimes refresh the page and sometimes redirect.

Comment: My crystal ball unfortunately is broken I don't know what do you want to do as well ;) You need to describe better what do you need...

Comment: @biesior I'm sorry for not explaining myself better. What about now?

Answer (score 1):

If I understand what you are trying to do, it sounds like, when a user submits a form, if that form has errors, you want them taken back to that form page with the data in that form?  Refreshing the web page won't help, they'll have lost all their input data.  Redirecting is also not the right way to achieve this.  You need to rerender the original form page - you have all the data they submitted, so you can rerender it.  If there's anything missing from the data, then you may need to add that in a hidden form field.  This is a very common requirement for web applications, and rerendering is the way to do it.  Using the Play form API, this is quite simple, simply pass the form that failed validation into the template that renders it, and you're done.

Read the docs here:

http://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.2.x/JavaForms

The section you want is handling form failure, basically you do something like this:

```
if (userForm.hasErrors()) {
    return badRequest(views.html.form.render(userForm));
} else {
    User user = userForm.get();
    return ok("Got user " + user);
}
```